# CartoDB Infowindow color

Tags: carto, infowindow

CartoDB offers 7 presets for Infowindows.
can i change the color of the infowinfow itself, beyond the 7 presets?
e.g. i want a infowindow with a grey header, or a infowindow completely grey with white text.
i think i have to edit e.g. this class: "class="cartodb-popup header blue v2"
but how and where?

Answer (score 2):

You can do some tricks by using the custom HTML option for the infowindows and add some custom styles there.

For example:

```
<div class="cartodb-popup v2" style="background: grey;">
<a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close">x</a>
<div class="cartodb-popup-content-wrapper">
<div class="cartodb-popup-content">
  <h4>description</h4>
  <p>{{description}}</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="cartodb-popup-tip-container"></div>
</div>
```

[image: Example]

I also recommend to take a look at this blogpost about [fully customizing infowindows](http://blog.cartodb.com/full-editing-of-infowindow-html/).

In order to get a more advanced customization of the infowindows you'll need to use the Javascript library CartoDB.js.